# Mootools Element clone

Tags: javascript, oop, object, mootools, jquery-ui-sortable

I'm working with sortable menu in Mootols, and trying to implement 'revert' option. I've come up with quite a simple solution:

1. Create root element clone at the beggining.
2. Edit menu.
3. When undo is clicked:
   a) root element is cleared with empty().
   b) I'm creating another clone of my menuCopy Element children.
   c) root element is adopting clone of menuCopy children.

Somehow it works only once - after that my menu copy becomes empty root element. So far I'm failing with tracing the issue. Would appreciate help. Here are important parts of code:

```
this.menuCopy = $(this.options.menu).clone(true,true);
```

This part is called after:

a) initialisation
b) saving menu (so the reverting goes back to the save point)

```
    $(self.options.menu).empty();
    var listContentsCopy=self.menuCopy.getChildren().clone(true,true);
    $(self.options.menu).adopt(listContentsCopy);
```

Comment: Found mistake:

    var listContentsCopy=self.menuCopy.getChildren().clone(true,true);

should be:

    var listContentsCopy=self.menuCopy.clone(true,true).getChildren();

I knew it's something dumb! :)

Answer (score 1):

Looking at you code something like this may be a bit easier:

```
this.menuCopy = $(this.options.menu).getChildren().clone(true,true);
```

Then

```
$(self.options.menu).empty().adopt(this.menuCopy);
```

Just a thought, seems a bit more light weight and easier to read.